# How do I force a static generic method's return type?

Tags: java, generics, java-7

Having a class hierarchy:

```
String child = null;
Object parent = child;
```

How do I force [`Sets.newHashSet(E...)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet(E...)) to return a `Set<Object>` while passing `String` arguments?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify generic return type with:

```
Sets.<Object>newHashSet(child);
```

Maybe it would be OK for you to return `Set<? extends Object>`, then you can write it as a return type:

```
public Set<? extends Object> myMethod() {
    return Sets.newHashSet(child);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You pass the type argument explicitly to `newHashSet`:

```
Sets.<Object>newHashSet(child);
```

If the type argument isn't passed explicitly the type is inferred and in this case it's inferred to the wrong type, presumably `String`.

It seems you're using [Guava's Sets](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet()). The method signature is the following:

```
public static <E> HashSet<E> newHashSet()
```

As you can see `newHashSet()` takes a type parameter `E`. The result is `HashSet<E>`. `E` is inferred to be `String`, but you've specified the method to return `Set<Object>`. The solution is to either help the compiler or loosen the restriction in the return type to `Set<? extends Object>`.

Answer (score 3):

`newHashSet` will always return the type of its generic type argument. Since the type of `child` is `String` the compiler will infer the generic type to be `String` and the function will return a `HashSet<String>`.

You can simply pass it a `Object` instead by casting `child` explicitly to force the compiler to infer `Object` as the generic type instead:

```
Sets.newHashSet((Object) child);
```

Alternatively you can force the generic type and the compiler can now see that the cast is trivial:

```
Sets.<Object>newHashSet(child);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, this compiles just fine; the inference takes into account of the target type.

```
public Set<Object> myMethod() {
    return Sets.newHashSet(child);
}
```

Using JDK's API:

```
public Set<Object> myMethod() {
    return Collections.singleton(child); // Works too
}
```

In Java 5, 6, 7 the inference on this call is done on argument types alone.